# WPF ComboBox changing when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectionchanged

I have a ComboBox of Employers.  Upon selecting an Employer, a table is populated with Employer specific data:

```
        <ComboBox Name="EmployerListBox"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployerCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Width="150" />
```

Here is the property to which it is binding and a method that checks to see if the table is dirty.  If the table is dirty, then the user is prompted that changes will be lost if they change Employer:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Selected Employer
    /// </summary>
    public String SelectedEmployer
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedEmployer;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedEmployer != value && CanChangeEmployer())
            {
                _SelectedEmployer = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.SelectedEmployer);
                GetGarnishmentsTableView();
            }
        }
    }
    private String _SelectedEmployer = "";


    /// <summary>
    /// Method that executes each time user wants to change employers
    /// </summary>
    public Boolean CanChangeEmployer()
    {
        Boolean _returnValue = true;

        if (GarnishmentsTableIsDirty)
        {
            _returnValue = false;

            MessageBoxResult _change =
                MessageBox.Show("There are unsaved changes.  " +
                                "Changing Employers will lose any unsaved changes.  \n\n" +
                                "Are you sure you want to change Employers?", "Unsaved Changes", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (_change == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                // OK to switch employers
                _returnValue = true;
            }
        }

        return _returnValue;
    }
```

Everything appears to work correctly:

- User selects Employer ('KMH') which updates table.
- User makes a change to the table.
- User then selects a different Employer ('MPC')
- User is prompted that changes will be lost
- User selects 'No' and CanChangeEmployers returns 'false'
- SelectedEmployer does NOT change (skips the if {} block)

Yet back in the GUI the Employer option changes to the Employer the user selected ('MPC'), even though SelectedEmployer hasn't changed.

When I Snoop the ComboBox, I see that that ComboBox SelectedItem is correctly set to the original Employer ('KMH') but SelectedValue and SelectionBoxItem are both set to the new Employer ('MPC').

I then tried binding ComboBox->SelectedValue to SelectedEmployer:

```
        <ComboBox Name="EmployerListBox"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployerCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEmployer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                  Width="150" />
```

And the GUI is the same, incorrect company being displayed.  But this time Snoop shows that ComboBox->SelectedValue is correctly set to the original Employer ('KMH') but SelectedItem and SelectionBoxItem are both set to the new Employer ('MPC').

How do I correctly bind SelectedEmployer so that the GUI matches the selected employer?

Comment: Try calling NotifyPropertyChanged(...) in the case where CanChangeEmployer() returns false, otherwise the binding subsystem may be assuming that the SelectedEmployer property has actually been set to the value specified whereas in reality it has not been updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel combobox selection in WPF with MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800032/cancel-combobox-selection-in-wpf-with-mvvm)